# Why does the DOA: Dead or Alive film have an additional DOA in the title?

Tags: title, doa-dead-or-alive

DOA: Dead or Alive is a film based on the game series Dead or Alive. But the game series didn't have DOA in the title. So why does the filmmaker add an additional DOA in the title? Was that only for styling or was there some other *behind the curtain* reasons?

Answer (score 25):

Quite possibly to avoid confusion with the 1999 Japanese film *Dead Or Alive*, which was a yakuza film having nothing to do with the video game series. There was also a 1950 film *D.O.A.* and its 1988 remake starring Dennis Quaid. The title of these films stands for "Dead On Arrival" and are about a man who has been poisoned and must solve his own murder before he succumbs.

So, when you can't use "Dead or Alive" or even "DOA" as a title without causing confusion, what do you do? You use both!

Comment: Obviously that won't cause any confusion at all....